# How do you turn a minimal CIF description into a complete one?

Tags: structural-biology, coot, ccp4

I have a CIF file that I downloaded from the PDB, but if I try to use it in Coot, it complains that it is not a complete CIF definition.  [This page](http://www.ccp4.ac.uk/html/libcheck.html#examples_complete) provides a batch script that I may be able to tease apart to suit my needs, but I thought there was a way to do this from within the CCP4 Program Suite GUI/job manager.

Maddeningly, I see in my project job history a couple "dictionary" jobs where I did this, but I utterly forgot how I set them up (forgive the asinine names):

[image: CCP4 dictionary jobs]

When I try to use the Monomer Library Sketcher (under Refinement/Restraint Preparation) and open a CIF ("mmCIF") file, nothing happens.

Also under the sketcher, I can severely abuse the "Load Monomer from Library" and it looks like I get the right thing:

[image: load monomer from library dialog]

However, when setting up the above, it throws "Error: can't read "monomer_lib(code,n..." warnings, then when running it generates the Geometry file (seemingly successfully) then says that Libcheck failed when trying to create the coordinate file.

---

If there are other solutions, I'd be interested as well.  I've used [PRODRG](http://davapc1.bioch.dundee.ac.uk/prodrg/) to create CIF files before with its draw tool, but it can be a bit clumsy, it ignores how I drew my double bonds, and it creates new names for all the atoms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite as ideal as I had hoped, but it works:

1. Get and install [CCP4](http://www.ccp4.ac.uk/download/os.php).
2. Obtain minimal CIF file from PDB or elsewhere.  Save to some folder easy to get at with the console.
3. Launch console and `cd` to folder with the minimal definition.
4. Run `libcheck` by typing it and hitting return

   - If it complains it's not found, the CCP4 `bin` directory may not be in your PATH environment variable.  You can get around this by specifing the full path to the program, e.g.: `c:\CCP4-Packages\ccp4-6.1.13\bin\libcheck.exe` (may vary with version)
5. Say "Y" or "A" at the `_DOC:` prompt for some more files, "N" if you don't care (I generally don't)
6. At the `-->` prompts, specify:

   - the input file, e.g.: `file_l: ABC.cif`
   - the monomer: `mon: ABC`
   - output file name: `file_o: ABC_out`
7. Leave a prompt blank and hit return to start processing.

If it runs successfully it might look something like this:

```
C:\Users\Nick>libcheck

  --- LIBCHECK --- /Vers 4.2.8   ; 02.06.2009/


  Do you want to have FILE-DOCUMENT /libcheck.doc/ ? /<N>/Y/A :
    N - means without DOC-file
    Y - with new contents
    A - means to keep old contents and add new information
        with DOC-file program creates batch file: libcheck.bat
 _DOC:n


 #
 #      Keywords:
 #
 #FILE_L:   < >  - additional library, " " means without this file
 #MON:      < >  - give info about this monomer
 ... (shortened) ...
 #SRCH: <N>/Y/0  - Y - global search, 0 - for MON from PDB_file
 #                 (only with NODIST = N)

 #---  type "keyword   parameters" and/or ---
 #---  press key "CR" to run program      ---
 -->file_l: ABC.cif
 -->mon: ABC
 -->file_o: ABC_out
 -->
 MON   : ABC
 -------------
 Output file   :ABC_comp
 Input user lib:ABC.cif
 _chem_comp.name "DRUG INTERMEDIATE"

          17          55
 "DRUG INTERMEDIATE"

 -------------
 Keywords:
 HFLAG : Y
 COOR  : N
 LCOOR : Y
 SRCH  : 0
 REF   : Y
 NODIST: Y
 ERROR ==> In the loop containing the item_chem_comp.three_letter_code
 ERROR ==> The number of expected items and the number existing items do not match
 ERROR ==> The number of expected items is    7
  NUMBER OF MONOMERS IN THE LIBRARY          :     1
                with complete description    :     0
  NUMBER OF MODIFICATIONS                    :     0
  NUMBER OF LINKS                            :     0
  I am reading libraries. Please wait.
      - energy parameters
      - monomer"s description (links & mod )
  I am reading library. Please wait.
      - monomer"s description
  WARNING : monomer:ABC      - has the minimal description.
  now monomer:ABC      - has complete description.
  I will check it.
 * CIFile  : ABC_out_ABC.cif
 * PDBfile : ABC_out_ABC.pdb
 * Plotfile: ABC_out_ABC.ps
  I am writing new description to
  file: ABC_out.lib

C:\Users\Nick>
```

It yields the following output files:

- `(file_o)`: looks like a CIF file with lots of whitespace and records stripped out
- **`(file_o)`.lib: the desired, complete definition file**
- `(file_o)`_`(mon)`.cif: an even more minimal CIF file with only XYZ coords
- `(file_o)`_`(mon)`.pdb: a PDB file
- `(file_o)`_`(mon)`.ps: a document with a stereo labeled diagram, and lists of bonds, angles, chirality (centers?) and planes.  Can convert it to the easier-to-use PDF format using this http://www.ps2pdf.com/convert.htm, or other tools.